# The heaviest induced subgraph problem

Tags: graphs, optimization, approximation, greedy-algorithms

I am interested in such a combinatorial problem: given a graph $G=(V, E)$ and a weight functions $w_v: V \mapsto R$, and $w_e: E \mapsto R$ we are asking about such a induced subgraph $G' = (V', E')$ of $G$ that maximizes the sum:
$
\sum_{e \in E'} w_e(e) + \sum_{v \in V'} w_v(v)
$.

The problem is **NP-H**ard (by the reduction from maximum clique problem) so any suggestions for approximation solutions (even greedy) and links to the literature would be appreciated.

Comment: @Juho First of all, I would like to know if such a problem has been considered. Any study, including a paper with experimental results is welcome.

Comment: Yes, it's been studied in great details.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Hardness_of_approximation

Comment: Search also for Weighted Clique.

Comment: In the literature, the heaviest $k$-subgraph problem is your problem where all vertices have weight 1.

Comment: @Juho For example [here](https://cedric.cnam.fr/fichiers/RC384.pdf) heaviest $k$-subgraph problem is discussed, however it is not the same (but quite similar) as you are allowed to take but specified $k$ different vertices. In the case I am asking about you can take any amount of nodes. 
So, if you have found anything closer than the paper by Alain Billionnet mentioned above please point it out - it would be meaningful for me.

Comment: @ŁukaszKuszner The problem is just rephrased to a decision problem instead of an optimization problem. I think that you can easily incorporate this into their MIP models by replacing constraint (1) by e.g., $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \geq 1$.

Comment: @Juho This is completely unobvious for me, specially that all weights in the Billionnet's paper are nonnegative.

Comment: If all positive weights, we just take the entire graph. The special case where edges have positive weights, and vertices have negative weights can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: @ChaoXu This would be interesting. How can you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
Let's consider a special case of the problem where vertex has negative weight and edges have positive weight. 
So $w_v: V\to \R^-$ and $w_e: E\to \R^+$.

Finding the heaviest induced subgraph is equivalent to a min-$st$-cut computation on a suitable graph. We will refer to the slides about densest subgraph in [this presentation](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/gionis/dense.pdf).

Indeed, minimizing $w_e(E(V'))+w_v(V')$ is equivalent to minimizing $(-w_v(V')) + \frac{1}{2} w_e(E(V',\bar{V'})) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{v\in \bar{V'}} \deg(v)$. (Note the degree here are weighted degree, that is $\deg(v) =\sum_{e:v\in e} w_e(e)$) 
The derivation of the above fact is similar to slide 21.
Then, this can be solved easily by modeling it as a min-$st$-cut in some other graph (see slide 22). It is crucial to have negative vertex weights and positive edge weights for the reduction to work.